# How to change the url with extra parameter in IP itself?

Tags: javascript

I am having an URL where i can able to access my application, after applying filter i shold be able to pass the parameter with value and replace in the URL

```
window.location.search.substring(1)
```

Accessing application From this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/abcd123#bordered=true&titled=true
```

After Applying filter need to change the url to

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/abcd123?company_name=value#bordered&titled
```

I need to replace

```
"#bordered&titled" with "?company_name=value#bordered&titled"
```

Comment: What stopps you making the replace you described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String​.prototype​.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
 with [Array​.prototype​.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let str="http://localhost:3000/dashboard/abcd123#bordered=true&titled=true"

let result=str.split("#").join("?company_name=value#").replace(/=true/g,"")
console.log(result)
```